# Ajax call from button in tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tooltip

I’ve been trying to make an ajax call from a button that is inserted in a tooltip. I tried using bootstrap tooltip and tooltipster, but nothing seems to work, and I couldn’t  find a working example. Please help

Here is the more simple version of the code I’ve been trying to work out, using Bootstrap tooltip. I cannot make JQuery to recognize the click on the button once the tooltip is on screen

```
//=====================HTML and PHP===========================
//previously made a query to get the image source

<label class="label" data-toggle="tooltip">
<?php
if($row['prof_image'] != null && $row['prof_image'] != ''){
echo'<img class="rounded-circle img-thumbnail" id="avatar" src="'.htmlentities($row['prof_image']).'" alt="profile"/>';
}else{
echo'<img class="rounded-circle img-thumbnail" id="avatar" src="../uploads/profile/profile.png" alt="profile" style="max-width:70%;"/>';
}
</label>

//=================Javascript===========================

$('#avatar').tooltip({title: "<p>Update image or <button class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary' id='imgDel'>Delete</button></p>", html: true, placement: "bottom", delay: {show: 0, hide: 2000}}); //the tooltip has a button. When tootlip on screen I want to be able to press the button and make ajax call to delete image


$('#imgDel').click(function(){
alert('delete option!');  //I put an alert instead of ajax call to see if it works. It doesn’t
});
```

At this stage I'm trying to get an alert after pressing the button nested in the tooltip, but I can't even get this to work. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `$(document).on('click', '#imgDel', function(){})` instead of `$('#imgDel').click(function(){})` because when you init the click function the element with `#imgDel` is not exist.

```
$(document).on('click', '#imgDel', function(){
   alert('delete option!');
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew was something related, but couldn't figure it out how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: If it resolved your issue, please accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery selector bindings in your script are bound when your javascript loads.  In your code, when the javascript loads, it is looking for an element with id '#imgDel', which doesn't exist in the DOM yet.  ( it only appears in your DOM after your tool tip appears )
Due to this, the binding for your click handler is never made since the element it's trying to bind it to cannot be found.

Doing something like :

```
$(document).on("click", "#imgDel", function(e){
    alert("clicked !")
});
```

is a workable solution.  You could also try using the tooltip fired events noted in the bootstrap tooltip documentation.

```
$('#avatar').tooltip({title: "<p>Update image or <button class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary' id='imgDel'>Delete</button></p>", html: true, placement: "bottom", delay: {show: 0, hide: 2000}});

$('#avatar').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function(){
    $('#imgDel').click(function(){
        alert('delete option!');
    });

    // You can now insert any selectors or bindings related to your tooltip and its elements since
    // at this point your tooltip and its elements have been rendered into your DOM
});
```

This basically runs a function once the 'show.bs.tooltip' event is fired on your element, which runs after your tooltip is shown (there is also one for after your tooltip is hidden). The events triggered by the tooltip (on the element you attach the tooltip to) can be found in the bootstrap tooltip documentation : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(document).on("click", "#imgDel", function(e){
    alter("clicked !")
});
```

You can't use `$('#imgDel').click(function(){});` because the element '#imgDel' is not in the DOM when the page is loaded ;)